# convert float to String without rounding it?

Tags: java, numbers, rounding

I need to convert a float number to String without exponential anotation

```
Float x3 = 849071675f;
System.out.println(x3);
```

this code give 8.4907168E8!
I tried to use DecimalFormat but I had the problem of rounding
is give me 849071680!

```
  Float x3 = 849071675f;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
  df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
  System.out.println(df.format(x3));
```

I want just a string value of 849071675 ?

Thank you

Comment: You might need a double.

Comment: do you know how floating point works, and what is the difference with doubles, and with fixed-point?

Comment: A float cannot hold exactly 849071675. It doesn't have enough precision.

Comment: `String.format("%.0f", x3)`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the result is 849071680 I want 849071675 without rounding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was alluded too, `84907167` is a 27 bit value.
Floats are 32 bits wide with 8 bits reserved for the exponent.  So you are going to lose precision since the maximum `significand` is 24 bits.  So rounding is inevitable.  Recommend you use a double.

```
 System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(x3)));        
 System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(84907167));
 System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(84907167).length());
```

prints

```
1001100101000011111001010010100
101000011111001010010011111
27
```

For more on this, check out [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and [What Computer Scientists should know about floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: thankd @WJS , when I worked with double that is a 64 bits I got the value 8.4907167E7           Double d = 84907167d;
System.out.println(d);

Comment: Yep.  And others in the comments suggested that too.  BTW, the first link in my answer is pretty straightforward.  The second one is a tougher read.